# Saw Resonator based Transmitter

Tags: rf, crystal

I'm want to design a RF 433.42MHz transmitter, but I'm not finding good documentation to help me design.

This is a model that I found [RO3112E](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/281/ro3112e-1317719.pdf) but it's not clear to me how do I calculate the components (resistor, capacitor, etc).

I found this [design node](https://wireless.murata.com/media/products/apnotes/sawbasedtransmitter.pdf) , but is intended for 433.92MHz.

How would be the circuit to aply this resonator, and how would be calculated the components?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the design in many Simulator tools that can do Bode,gain phase plots with the RLC, stray C, transistor gm or beta and GBW, and compute f peak , measure To,  the peak parabolic center frequency vs temperature, just the same as 32 kHz resonators except you are dealing with UHF layouts. All the values are given and choose the Tx or LO model for your application.

Temp compensation over a wide temperature is tricky but can be done with Varicap’s , an TL01 temp sensor and a DAC.

A Network or Spectrum Analyzer with the choke helps to test the insertion loss and phase parameters and compare with the simulation model.

Falstad’s filter spectrum simulator can do this in a very short amount of time. https://www.falstad.com/afilter/.  Then you can do a proof of concept in the time domain by copying all the schematic and pasting into the [time domain](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%202.9224283781234943%2050%205%2050%0Al%2080%20128%2080%20304%200%200.01%20-0.010350156368318772%0Ac%20192%20128%20192%20224%200%200.00009999999999999999%200.7040989697160849%0At%20256%20128%20304%20128%200%201%200.6499517680655678%200.7040989697160849%20100%0Ac%20192%20224%20192%20304%200%200.00009999999999999999%20-0.6538852313628967%0Aw%2080%20304%20192%20304%200%0Aw%2080%20128%20192%20128%200%0Aw%20192%20128%20256%20128%200%0Aw%20192%20224%20304%20224%200%0Aw%20304%20144%20304%20224%200%0Aw%20304%20112%20352%20112%200%0Ar%20352%20112%20352%20304%200%201000%0Aw%20192%20304%20352%20304%200%0Ar%20304%20112%20304%2048%200%20100%0AR%20304%2048%20256%2048%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20304%20224%20304%20256%200%0AO%20352%20112%20432%20112%200%0Ax%20150%20182%20170%20185%204%2016%20C1%0Ax%20150%20271%20170%20274%204%2016%20C2%0A403%20352%20128%20480%20192%200%2015_64_0_4098_5_0.1_0_1%0Ao%2015%2032%200%204106%205%200.00009765625%200%201%0A)  on a blank page and learn how to set the options> other options > time sample rate with input Vdc , Gnd , and add scope traces with your mouse only any line or part with many options.

But have to know how to choose RF transistors on a copper breadboard for testing with soldered RF jacks and impedance dividers to a 50 Ohm terminated spectrum analyzer or DSO.

Or just buy one RF Tx and test it and learn. They are cheap.

Comment: Do you understand this answer? If not which part?

Comment: It's a lot of information, but I undestod in general.. I will start doing some simulations, and try to get the right values... If I have any doubts in the process I post here for you give me a hand hehe... thanks in advance

Comment: the only part you cannot simulate is the PTC/NTC parabolic amplitude vs temp curve easily.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use that design node.  Based on the motational inductance and capacitance, the two resonators have characteristic impedances that are within 20% of each other; that means that a circuit that oscillates for one should work or the other.

It's going to be a challenge for you -- oscillator design isn't trivial.